# Setting MySQL slow query to less than 1 second

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a heavily loaded LAMP system serving about 40 requests per second and doing about 300 MySQL queries per second. Here is the output of MySQLAdmin status:

```
Uptime: 5051  Threads: 1  Questions: 1418500  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 456  
Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 450  Queries per second avg: 280.835
```

However, the global status show about 5-10% table lock contention.

So, I want to figure out the queries that are taking longer time.

**Is it possible to set the slow query log to less than one second? For my queries, even execution time of 100ms is high.**

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just set [`long_query_time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) to the value you want. If you want to log queries that take longer than 100ms, you would set it to `0.1`.

The ability to set this option to a value less than 1 was [added in MySQL 5.1.21](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time).

Comment: My host is using version 5.0.95-log, any solution for that?

Comment: Yes, become the system administrator and run your server yourself. We're generally unable to help in situations where you are _not_ the server administrator.

Comment: @adwiv Are you on a shared host with that much traffic??

Comment: @WesleyDavid No its a standard VPS with about 2GB RAM on centos 5.8. I have done the `yum update` and `yum upgrade` but it won't upgrade the mysql server version. I was not sure if installing from some other repository will break any dependencies. Anyways I am going to try the upgrade anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You must be running EL5, then. EL6 came with MySQL 5.1, or you can get a third party repository such as remi to use MySQL 5.5 or higher.

Comment: @adwiv What version is on the server and what version is in the repos? If you change to RPMForge, you'll need to uninstall the current MySQL and re-install from the alternate repo, then make sure to block the default repo for MySQL. yum priorities, etc. I can take a look at it if you'd like.

Comment: @WesleyDavid Thanks. We are now planning to migrate to a newly provisioned VPS server. The server is used primarily for logging analytics data, so there will not be a need for migrating the existing data, only the scripts and schema. So hopefully the migration path would be simpler and without any downtime. Thanks.

Comment: @adwiv Using packages that are newer than the official EL repos can be really, really bad, so yeah, just do a version number migration and you'll be good.